# SQL Select to keep out fields that are NULL

Tags: sql, firebird, filemaker

I am trying to connect a Filemaker DB to Firebird SQL DB in both ways import to FM and export back to Firebird DB.
So far it works using the MBS Plug-in but FM 13 Pro canot handle `NULL`.

That means that for example Timestamp fields that are empty (`NULL`) produce a `"0"` value.
Thats means in Time something like `01.01.1889 00:00:00`.

So my idea was to simply ignore fields containing `NULL`.

But here my poor knowlege stops.

First I thought I can do this with `WHERE`, but this is ignoring whole records sets:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IS NOT NULL
```

Also I tried to filter it later on like this:

```
If (IsEmpty (MBS("SQL.GetFieldAsDateTime"; $command; "FIELD")  ) = 0 ; MBS("SQL.GetFieldAsDateTime"; $command; "FIELD"))
```

With no result either.

Comment: Is it possible that the NULL values are string values of "NULL"?

Comment: I used a DB Editor and its NULL and not "NULL". The WHERE filter works but it filters whole records instead of single field, what I actualy need to do.

Comment: I'm not sure you can ignore a FIELD which is a NULL. That would mean that different records will have different numbers of fields.

You could use COALESCE to have a default value if the timestamp field is NULL.

Comment: I dont want the field to get changed when its null. Only after i did and edit the field which the timestamp is used for.

Comment: I do not fully understand you Issue; you have two Databases and want to sync them? or only one table? are the coloums the same (w/o the no NULL with FM 13)

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct answer to halfbit's suggestion, which is correct but not for this SQL dialect. In a query to provide a replacement value when a field is NULL you need to use COALESCE(x,y).  Where if X is null, Y will be used, and if Y is null then the field is NULL.  Thats why it is common for me to use it like COALESCE(table.field,'') such that a constant is always outputted if table.field happens to be NULL.

```
select COALESCE(null,'Hello') as stackoverflow from rdb$database
```

You can use [`COALESCE()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-coalesce) for more than two arguments, I just used two for conciseness.

Comment: I think i got this right, so i used select FIELD1, coalesce (null,'') as FIELD2 from TABLE    The '' means it inserts nothing. But that still seams to insert something that equals to the function NULL into the Filemaker field. What i need is to skip that totally so it does not change the field at all.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused.  Can FIELD1 be null?  If so you probably want to do select COALESCE(field1,'') as field2 from table

Comment: @MichaelMüller 'skipping' the field (which is not possible unless you exclude it from the select), would still yield a null in the table you insert it. `NULL` means unknown or value absent. You will need to use a specific replacement value if you don't want `NULL`, and most likely Filemaker treats empty string and `NULL` as the same value.

Comment: Its a timestamp data, FM is not interpreting NULL as NULL. It writes instead 1889 00:00:00 (or alike)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the special SQL dialect, but

```
SELECT field1, field2, value(field, 0), ...FROM TABLE
```

should help you:
`value` gives  the first argument, ie, your field if it is NOT NULL or the second argument if it is.

Comment: AHH! I did not thought that way. But should i really use 0 as argument instaed of NULL?

Comment: I tried it that way but it did not work: SELECT FIELD1, VALUE (FIELD2, NULL) FROM TABLE. Same with 0

Comment: I went trough the Firebird manual it seams that this does not work.

Comment: It is [`COALESCE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-coalesce.html) for Firebird